# Why am I getting this error in my script? awk: script.awk:19: “ syntax error

Tags: bash, awk

I have 2 text files

#### 1.txt

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;
GG;22222;
```

#### 2.txt

```
KK;WW;55555;11111;
KK;FF;ZZ;11111;
KK;RR;YY;11111;
```

I try to generate this `3.txt` output:

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;KK;FF;ZZ;KK;RR;YY;
GG;22222;
```

and after removing duplicates fields I should to have this

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;FF;ZZ;RR;YY;
GG;22222;
```

In simply words: in two files that are separated by `;` (FS=";"), if a field `$n` from file 1 is present in any location `$m` in file 2, where m,n is not 1, then append `$0(file2,m)` to `$0(file1,n)`. Duplicate fields must be avoided.

I'll attempt to sketch a solution

```
awk -f script.awk 2.txt 1.txt
```

where script is the following:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=";"
    OFS=";"
}

NR==FNR {
    allRecordsFile2[i++] = $0;
    next;
}

{
    for(r in allRecordsFile2)
    {
         split(allRecordsFile2[r],";",array)
         for(f in array)
         {
             for($2 through $n of file1 currently processed)
             {
                 if $n == f --> $0 = $0";"allRecordsFile2[r]
             }
         }
    }

    ## cleanup duplicates

    print $0
}
```

I still need to hammer out the cleanup duplicates, but probably this can be done by splitting `$0` by `";"` and using a counting array to keep track of duplicates.

But after running this script I return syntax errors

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>awk -f script.awk file2.txt file1.txt

awk: script.awk:17: for($2 through $n of filei currently processed)
awk: script.awk:17: “ syntax error
awk: script.awk:19: if $n == f --> $0 = $0";"allRecordsFile2[r]
awk: script.awk:19: “ syntax error
awk: script.awk:19: if $n == f --> $0 = $0";"allRecordsFile2[r]
awk: script.awk:19: “ syntax error
errcount:3
```

[image: syntax error]

Comment: Not 100% on this, but your whole `FS=";" OFS=";"` seems wrong. It should be `IFS=";"` and `OIFS=$IFS` and at the end of the script you should simply set `IFS=$OIFS` to set the original IFS back again.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 nothing change, it return to me same errors

Comment: Yes, I know. But when you set `FS=";"` and `OFS=";"` those are two variables that have nothing to do with anything. So you were never setting the `IFS` value. And the whole reason to set `OIFS` is to reset the `IFS` value after the script is done.

Comment: @Giacomo1968+ that's quite wrong. `FS` (input) and `OFS` (output) **are** the correct variables in `awk`. `IFS` is used only in **shell** and _this is not a shell script_.  (And even in shell you only need to set IFS _back_ if the script is 'sourced' rather than run in a subshell.)

Comment: This question is more appropriate for stack overflow.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying sequential reads and controlling based on `FNR`/`NR`, why not use `getline` to read from `2.txt` and split on `';'` and then build the output string (`o` below) concatenating unique components from each line? You could do something similar to:

```
awk '{
        printf "%s", $0
    }
    /^BB/ {
        o = ""
        while (getline tmp < "2.txt") {
            n = split (tmp,arr,";")
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
                if(!match($0,arr[i]) && !match(o,arr[i]))
                    o=o arr[i]";"
        }
        printf "%s", o
    }
    {
        print ""
    }
' 1.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `1.txt` and `2.txt` (which you have misnamed `1.txt` again), you would receive:

```
$ awk '{
>         printf "%s", $0
>     }
>     /^BB/ {
>         o = ""
>         while (getline tmp < "2.txt") {
>             n = split (tmp,arr,";")
>             for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
>                 if(!match($0,arr[i]) && !match(o,arr[i]))
>                     o=o arr[i]";"
>         }
>         printf "%s", o
>     }
>     {
>         print ""
>     }
> ' 1.txt
AA;00000;
BB;11111;KK;WW;55555;FF;ZZ;RR;YY;
GG;22222;
```

Which looks like what you want.

---

**As A Script Taking Two-Filenames As Arguments**

Windows should follow the same conventions using `ARGV`. Note, you do not include the single quotations around the rules when running within an `awk` script, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

NR != FNR {
    exit
}
{
    printf "%s", $0
}
/^BB/ {
    o = ""
    while (getline tmp < ARGV[2]) {
        n = split (tmp,arr,";")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            if(!match($0,arr[i]) && !match(o,arr[i]))
                o=o arr[i]";"
    }
    printf "%s", o
}
{
    print ""
}
```

(**note:** you will need to change the `/usr/bin/awk` interpreter to whatever you have)

Usage would be, e.g. `./test.awk 1.txt 2.txt`

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: ```C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin>awk -f script.awk 2.txt 1.txt
awk: script.awk:1: awk -F';' '{
awk: script.awk:1:       ^ invalid char ''' in expression``` , https://i.imgur.com/EjF4HwT.png

Comment: Oh, you don't include the quotes when you create a script. Those are not needed. Also, you can completely omit the `-F';'` the change of `FS` isn't needed the way I have the script working (that was from an earlier test)

Comment: David, your windows script works but is not perfect. I try to explain why. If my **1**.txt file have this row `;d(2);http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;` and into **2**.txt I have this row `;Link;A_x-y.7z;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;d(2);` I can't generate a **3**.txt file with row `;d(2);http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;Link;A_x-y.7z;`

Comment: you can think line in **1**.txt `;d(2);http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;` as `;AA;BB;`, and you can think line in **2**.txt `;Link;A_x-y.7z;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1;d(2);` as `;CC;DD;BB;AA;`. **3**.txt line output you can consider it as `;AA;BB;;CC;DD;`

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to take a look in the morning (very late here... braindead). I suspect it has to do with the `(...)` being taken as a REGEX grouping in `match()` as the first parameter is a REGEX and by passing `$0` and `o` both will be treated as "Dynamic Regular Expressions* in `awk` speak. See [GNU Awk User's Guide - 3.6 Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)

Comment: I simplified it this way because otherwise it became too difficult if the fields contain symbols like ?, *, /. However the delimiter symbol `;` it is never present.

Comment: I read that for last request maybe your script should a couple of issues. They tell to ignore the `match` problem, you will have false positives if you have a field in `2.txt` which read `11` and `111` and `1111` .... . Instead of using `match` make use of `index`. The latter works string-based and not regular expression based. And try to search for `";" arr[i] ";"` in the string `";" $0 ";"`

Comment: Yes, but you have to understand, your question asked was to identify a line that began with `"BBB"` It wasn't until you later provided a comment that you indicate your first field could actually be something like `;d(2);ht` -- there is a big difference in how you would approach handling the inputs. I'll have to look further into how to handle potential REGEX operators in that first field.

Comment: you're right, I post a new question for this

Answer (score 2):

Using the keys of an associative array is handy to handle duplicate items.
This requires GNU awk for the multi-dimensional array

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }
NR == FNR {
    for (i=1; i<NF-1; i++)
        f2[$(NF-1)][$i] = ++n
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    # this joins all the 2nd-level indices
    # the order of them is undefined.
    for (x in f2) {
        s = ""
        for (y in f2[x])
            s = s y OFS
        a[x] = s
    }
}
$(NF - 1) in a { $NF = a[$(NF-1)] }
1
```

then

```bsh
gawk -f script.awk {2,1}.txt
```

produces

```
AA;00000;
BB;11111;55555;WW;KK;RR;YY;FF;ZZ;
GG;22222;
```

---

I'll need more evidence that it "doesn't work" with URLs:

```bsh
$ cat 1.txt
AA;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=00000;
BB;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=11111;
GG;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=22222;

$ cat 2.txt
KK;WW;55555;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=11111;
KK;FF;ZZ;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=11111;
KK;RR;YY;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=11111;

$ gawk -f script.awk {2,1}.txt
AA;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=00000;
BB;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=11111;55555;WW;KK;RR;YY;FF;ZZ;
GG;http://a.o/f/i.p?t=22222;
```

Comment: If I replace `00000` between `;` separators with text data like `http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1` still between separators `;` script doesn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming that the join field is NF-1,is that right? Your sample input and output suggests that.

Comment: yes, it is, Problem is about text data in field, because if text is `AA` it works but if text is `http://a.o/f/i.p?t=1` it doesn't

Comment: syntax errors for line 4 and 12, https://i.imgur.com/za60qAf.png

Comment: I did say this solution requires GNU awk.

Comment: Yes, I test on linux directly your script, but doesn't work. I use this example: **1**.txt has `AA;BB;` **2**.txt `CC;DD;BB;AA` => your script produce `AA;BB;` and not `AA;BB;CC;DD`, you can see here https://imgur.com/hnL0jQ4.png

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get correct output with gawk version 5.1.0

Comment: I try also another code `BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!seen[$i]++){ val=(val?val OFS:"")$i }
  }
  print val
  delete seen
  val=""
}` - but it works only if you have a single record (=only one row) for both files

Comment: I use paste command to combine both the files and then processing its output by awk command.

`paste 1st.txt 2nd.txt | awk -f tst.awk > "3.txt"`

Comment: Can you think that is there a fix to extend for multiple rows?